# What am I doing wrong with the following delete query?

Tags: mysql

I want to create a `procedure` in MYSQL that will run every hour that will `delete` all entries in the `Document` table. I want to delete all Documents that have access level of 5 if they are posted by people from France after one year if these users were under 18 years of age at the time the Document was posted

The code below gives me an error and tells me check my syntax. 
Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix the code up so its a working procedure?

```
CREATE EVENT hourlydelete
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR
DO CALL delete_Document();

DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE PROCEDURE delete_Document()
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM Document
    WHERE   (Document.idPerson = Person.idPerson AND Person.Country = 'France' AND Document.AccessLevel = 5)
    AND     ((DATEDIFF(Document.Posted,Person.DateOfBirth) / 365) < 18) 
    AND     ((DATEDIFF(NOW(), Document.Posted)/365) > 3)
    ORDER by Document.idPerson

    END
    $$
    DELIMITER;
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove

```
ORDER by Document.idPerson
```

Since, you're not using a `SELECT` query there is no resultset to `ORDER BY`.

The multi-table syntax for `DELETE` statement in MySQL is

```
DELETE FROM t1, t2 USING t1 INNER JOIN t2 INNER JOIN t3
WHERE t1.id = t2.id AND t2.id = t3.id;
```

where the records get deleted from `t1` and `t2` (before `USING`) but not `t3`.

So, you actually need to use

```
DELETE FROM Document USING Document INNER JOIN Person
WHERE ...
```

This makes sure that only `Document` records get deleted and `Person` is used to specify the criterion only. Also, note that `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` cannot be used with multi-table `DELETE`s.

Comment: thanks for that, but does the rest of the query follow the 3 conditions I want?

Comment: An order by clause in a delete statement is valid in mysql, because mysql allows a limit clause with delete too. Removing it will ave no effect.

Comment: @Bohemian hi, would you have any suggestions to what is causing the problem if not the Order by clause Bohemian?

Comment: I removed the ORDER by statement but still same error and it occurs at `END $$ DELIMITER`

Comment: @corybaxter Please, check the multi-table MySQL syntax updated in my answer.

Comment: Still the same error at the same spot =( this ones a tricky one looks like

Comment: Try keeping the simplest delete possible that doesn't delete anything with WHERE 1=2 just to check if the error is with the block or the delete statement.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a semi-colon `;` at the end of the `DELETE` statement!

Also, your conditions seem to be "either a) or b) or c)", but you've used `AND` logic, when you probably want `OR` logic.

Change the main `AND` operators to `OR`, and add the semi-colon:

```
DELETE FROM Document
WHERE (Document.idPerson = Person.idPerson AND Person.Country = 'France' AND Document.AccessLevel = 5)
OR ((DATEDIFF(Document.Posted,Person.DateOfBirth) / 365) < 18) 
OR ((DATEDIFF(NOW(), Document.Posted)/365) > 3); -- Add a semi colon!
```

Comment: But I want all the conditions to meet, only then it should delete the data. Would the OR statement do the job?

Comment: Are you *sure* you want `AND`??? It seems very unlikely - they are each valid reasons and the conditions are unrelated. The presence or absence of the order by will have no effect on which rows get deleted - it only matters wen deleting with a `limit` claus.

Comment: I want to delete all Documents that have access level of 5 if they are posted by people from France after one
year if these users were under 18 years of age at the time the Document was posted.

Comment: Also the the procedure will be run hourlyand will
remove any qualifying Documents which are older than 3years at the time the procedure is run.

Comment: I think OP needs AND but either AND/OR shouldn't cause a syntax error. It should just fail to delete the right records.

Comment: Found it - see edited answer. You're missing a semi colon after the DELETE statement - the `END` was being considered as part of the DELETE.